# Regular expression to match one from two groups

Tags: python, regex

I want to perform operation like select any one suitable group from two 
for e.g:

```
gmail.com|gmail.co.in
```

this gives me direct result but how can I write regular expression for python to map email id for above case.
Note. I just want to map 3 char after dot or max two group of dot and 2 character

I tried writing regex as :

```
[\w]+\.?[\w]{3}|[[\w]{2}\.?]{2}
```

but wont give me expected results

If tried to use () returns group for e.g:`abcd@gmail.com` will return `gmail.com` but need to retrieve whole email address.

Comment: `[[\w]{2}\.?]` what are you trying to do here? Here `[[\w]` is a character class containing `[` and `\w`, and the last `]` matches the character `]`.

Comment: ya thats what. i was just trying to group two groups. I mean [\w] and \. group this two as one for repetations. but dont know how to do it

Comment: `(` and `)` are used for grouping, not `[` and `]`.

Comment: I have already mentioned that using () returns the grouped string in (). i.e it will return just gmail.com or gmail.co.in but I want the whole string matched for email. I tried using this regex:  [\s]*[\w+\._-]+[\s]?@[\s]?[\w]+\.[\w\.-]{3,5} but it truncates the last part if grater than 5 char

Comment: In the first part of the question it seems you're trying to match a domain. In the second part it seems you're trying to match an email address. It's confusing. I would suggest to use `\S+?@\S+` and then use an appropriate function/library to validate it.

Comment: I am trying to match whole email id but the thing is I know how to retireve the user name just confused regarding the domain part which can be in multiple form. So I just asked about domain part matching.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex :

```
\w+@\w+\.((\w{3})|(\w{2}\.\w{2}))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mB2vN9/1)

All you need here is put the first part as `\w+@\w+\.` then you just need to play with grouping and pipe.so the following pattern:

```
((\w{3})|(\w{2}\.\w{2}))
```

will match a string contain 3 word character or `(\w{2}\.\w{2})` that means a string with 2 word character then dot then string with 2 word character.

Comment: for this regex if input is given as abcd@gmail.com it gives output as  [('com', 'com', '')] instead of [abcd@gmail.com]. I dont want [com,com] as output as it affects my remaining code

Comment: @Angels its because of that `@` is not a word character and your first examples doesn't contain `@` , check out the edit

Comment: I have tried this after your edit suggestion still it gives same result  [\w+\._-]+@\w+\.((\w{3})|(\w{2}\.\w{2}))

Comment: @Angels What kind of function you used?

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps.

```
>>> import re
>>> y = re.search('(?P<user>\w+)@(?P<domain>[\w.]+)', 'abc@gmail.com')
>>> print y.group("user"), y.group("domain")
abc gmail.com
>>> y = re.search('(?P<user>\w+)@(?P<domain>[\w.]+)', 'abc@gmail.co.in')
>>> print y.group("user"), y.group("domain")
abc gmail.co.in
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this can help you.

```
email = 'abc@gmail.com'
user = email.split('@')[0]
domain = email.split('@')[1]
```